# How to set a persistent $PATH variable for single or all users

Tags: linux, debian, path

This question has been asked before online but with conflicting answers so I am looking for clarification.

What is the best way to add $PATH variables (below) in debian so that they are persitent for every user ?

I have used the below commands when logged in as root, which works fine but obviously when I reboot these are lost.

Another post I read suggested to paste the below lines into `.bashrc` or `.profile` but assume this will only work for the logged in user ? If so how would I set the below for all users ?

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/armv4l/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/armv5l/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/armv6l/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/i586/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/m68k/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/mips/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/mipsel/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/powerpc/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/powerpc-440fp/bin
```

Golang

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/go
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the PATH set for **all** users when they log in, set it in `etc/profile` which sets up the environment for login shells

You can add several components in one statement:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/xcompile/armv4l/bin:/etc/xcompile/armv5l/bin:etc/xcompile/armv6l/bin
```

If you want the PATH set for **individual** users when they log in, it should be set in `~/.profile`.

And if you want it set for  individual users every time they start an interactive shell, set it in `~/.bashrc`

For a more complete discussion of this see the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should not "mess" the `/etc/profile` it is more advisable to add it to a custom **sh** inside the `/etc/profile.d/yoursh.sh`. This will be imported for all users.

If you want for a single user you should use the `.profile` has it was said before or the `.bashrc` depending on the case.

Comment: I don't know how many systems use `/etc/profile.d`. Using `/etc/profile` will work anywhere

Comment: thanks @PiedPiper i tested the .profile file and that worked fine. I will try adding it to file /etc/profile and see how I get on !

Comment: both methods appear to work fine so will use the /etc/profile to set variable for all users - thanks for help @PiedPiper and Banjosa

Comment: @PiedPiper ok done my friend !